# Paper from 1969 not available ? is it possible?

Tags: research

I was looking for the following paper (and this keeps coming up).
I am not sure if it is copyrighted/available or not.

https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0081965

As a profane, I don't quite understand the process by which a paper from 1969 made by a university would not be publically accessible. Is it possible ?

Comment: Try clicking on "Download book pdf" on top of the page, it works for me. Heres the link: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBFb0081959.pdf

Comment: It seems to be accessible online if you are prepared to pay.  Some libraries may have paper copies of the original conference proceedings

Comment: Sorry my mistake, it worked because i clicked while connected to a university network. Doesn't work from mobile.

Comment: @cdwe: The paper is not freely available, but (this is for nicolas) the paper is in one of the volumes of the well known Springer-Verlag Lecture Notes in Mathematics series which you can find in most university libraries. In U.S. libraries they're (nearly always, if not always) shelved together in the QA3 .L28 location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the university has an access to Springer, then more or less recent papers (say, up to 20-years-old, I don't remember details) are available to download from the university domain. Older papers are paid. My university has such an access. Of course, I was also surprised that old articles are impossible to download without extra money.

Comment: Older papers are usually not freely available unless they're earlier than about 1920 or so, although there are some exceptions -- the London Mathematical Society seems to have all their journal publications, no matter how old (even 1800s material), locked behind paywalls.

Comment: that's crazy. why would a university give away funded work for someone else to collect money ? this is totally mindblowing. unless the author is getting the paycheck of those 5 downloads a year, paid nickels by some university..